# Compare two columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataframe

Using this as a starting point:

```py
a = [['10', '1.2', '4.2'], ['15', '70', '0.03'], ['8', '5', '0']]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])
```

which looks like

```
  one  two three
0   10  1.2   4.2
1   15  70   0.03
2    8   5     0
```

I want to use something like an `if` statement within pandas.

```py
if df['one'] >= df['two'] and df['one'] <= df['three']:
    df['que'] = df['one']
```

Basically, create a new column by checking each row via the `if` statement.

The docs say to use `.all` but there is no example...

Answer (score 221, accepted):

You could use [np.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). If `cond` is a boolean array, and `A` and `B` are arrays, then

```
C = np.where(cond, A, B)
```

defines C to be equal to `A` where `cond` is True, and `B` where `cond` is False.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = [['10', '1.2', '4.2'], ['15', '70', '0.03'], ['8', '5', '0']]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])

df['que'] = np.where((df['one'] >= df['two']) & (df['one'] <= df['three'])
                     , df['one'], np.nan)
```

yields

```
  one  two three  que
0  10  1.2   4.2   10
1  15   70  0.03  NaN
2   8    5     0  NaN
```

---

If you have more than one condition, then you could use [np.select](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) instead.
For example, if you wish `df['que']` to equal `df['two']` when `df['one'] < df['two']`, then

```
conditions = [
    (df['one'] >= df['two']) & (df['one'] <= df['three']), 
    df['one'] < df['two']]

choices = [df['one'], df['two']]

df['que'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
```

yields

```
  one  two three  que
0  10  1.2   4.2   10
1  15   70  0.03   70
2   8    5     0  NaN
```

If we can assume that `df['one'] >= df['two']` when `df['one'] < df['two']` is
False, then the conditions and choices could be simplified to

```
conditions = [
    df['one'] < df['two'],
    df['one'] <= df['three']]

choices = [df['two'], df['one']]
```

(The assumption may not be true if `df['one']` or `df['two']` contain NaNs.)

---

Note that

```
a = [['10', '1.2', '4.2'], ['15', '70', '0.03'], ['8', '5', '0']]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])
```

defines a DataFrame with string values. Since they look numeric, you might be better off converting those strings to floats:

```
df2 = df.astype(float)
```

This changes the results, however, since strings compare character-by-character, while floats are compared numerically.

```
In [61]: '10' <= '4.2'
Out[61]: True

In [62]: 10 <= 4.2
Out[62]: False
```

Answer (score 130):

You can use `.equals` to compare 2 columns:

```
df['col1'].equals(df['col2'])
```

or to compare 2 dataframes:

```
df1.equals(df2)
```

If they're equal, that statement will return `True`, else `False`.

Answer (score 34):

You could use apply() and do something like this

```
df['que'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['one'] if x['one'] >= x['two'] and x['one'] <= x['three'] else "", axis=1)
```

or if you prefer not to use a lambda

```
def que(x):
    if x['one'] >= x['two'] and x['one'] <= x['three']:
        return x['one']
    return ''
df['que'] = df.apply(que, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 14):

One way is to use a Boolean series to index the column `df['one']`. This gives you a new column where the `True` entries have the same value as the same row as `df['one']` and the `False` values are `NaN`.

The Boolean series is just given by your `if` statement (although it is necessary to use `&` instead of `and`):

```
>>> df['que'] = df['one'][(df['one'] >= df['two']) & (df['one'] <= df['three'])]
>>> df
    one two three   que
0   10  1.2 4.2      10
1   15  70  0.03    NaN
2   8   5   0       NaN
```

If you want the `NaN` values to be replaced by other values, you can use the `fillna` method on the new column `que`. I've used `0` instead of the empty string here:

```
>>> df['que'] = df['que'].fillna(0)
>>> df
    one two three   que
0   10  1.2   4.2    10
1   15   70  0.03     0
2    8    5     0     0
```

Answer (score 9):

Wrap each individual condition in parentheses, and then use the `&` operator to combine the conditions:

```
df.loc[(df['one'] >= df['two']) & (df['one'] <= df['three']), 'que'] = df['one']
```

You can fill the non-matching rows by just using `~` (the "not" operator) to invert the match:

```
df.loc[~ ((df['one'] >= df['two']) & (df['one'] <= df['three'])), 'que'] = ''
```

You need to use `&` and `~` rather than `and` and `not` because the `&` and `~` operators work element-by-element.

The final result:

```
df
Out[8]: 
  one  two three que
0  10  1.2   4.2  10
1  15   70  0.03    
2   8    5     0
```

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to add this answer for those who are trying to compare the equality of values in two columns that have `NaN` values, and get `False` when both values are `NaN`. By definition, `NaN` != `NaN` (See: [numpy.isnan(value) not the same as value == numpy.nan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528092/numpy-isnanvalue-not-the-same-as-value-numpy-nan)).

If you want the two `NaN` comparison to return `True`, you can use:

```
df['compare'] = (df["col_1"] == df["col_2"]) | (df["col_1"].isna() & df["col_2"].isna())
```

Answer (score 4):

Use lambda expression:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x['col1'] != x['col2'], axis = 1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `np.select` if you have multiple conditions to be checked from the dataframe and output a specific choice in a different column

```
conditions=[(condition1),(condition2)]
choices=["choice1","chocie2"]

df["new column"]=np.select=(condtion,choice,default=)
```

Note: No of conditions and no of choices should match, repeat text in choice if for two different conditions you have same choices

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html#pandas.Series.where):

```
df['que'] = df['one'].where((df['one'] >= df['two']) & (df['one'] <= df['three']))
```

or the method [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html):

```
df['que'] = df.loc[df.eval('(one >= two) & (two <= three)'), 'one']
```

Result:

```
  one  two three  que
0  10  1.2   4.2   10
1  15   70  0.03  NaN
2   8    5     0  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest to the OP's intuition is an inline if statement:

```
df['que'] = (df['one'] if ((df['one'] >= df['two']) and (df['one'] <= df['three']))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're here to compare values in two dataframe columns, you can use `eq()`:

```py
df['one'].eq(df['two'])
```

or `eval()`

```py
df.eval("one == two")
```

and if you want to reduce it to a single boolean, call `all()` on the result:

```py
df['one'].eq(df['two']).all()
# or
df.eval("one == two").all()
```

This is a more "robust" check than `equals()` because for `equals()` to return True, the column dtypes must match as well. So if one column is dtype `int` and the other is dtype `float`, `equals()` would return False even if the values are the same, whereas `eq().all()`/`eval().all()` simply compares the columns element-wise.

If your columns includes NaN values, then use the following (which leverages the fact that `NaN != NaN`):

```py
df.eval("one == two or one != one").all()
```

---

For OP's specific question, since the pattern is "A < B and B < C", you can use `between()`:

```py
cond = df['one'].between(df['two'], df['three'])
df['que'] = np.where(cond, df['one'], np.nan)
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @ccook5760's answer

> You can use .equals for columns or entire dataframes.
>
> ```
> df['col1'].equals(df['col2'])
> ```
>
> If they're equal, that statement will return True, else False.

For the equality to be verified, the columns must contain the same values in the same order and their indexes must be identical too.

If you wanted to check equality of two columns from two different dataframes where order of values is not important and may vary, you can sort the values first.

It is also important to reset the index of the series so that the equality can be verified based only on the values.

Here is one way to do it :

```
df1['col1'].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True).equals(df2['col2'].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True))
```

Same method, in a more readable way :

```
s1 = df1['col1'].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
s2 = df2['col2'].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
s1.equals(s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your columns contain the same values in the same order and they are numeric then use equality  else use .equals method

col1 contains: 58.1.2 , 29.2.4
col2 contains: 58.1.2 , 28.2.4

syntax:
**mydf['processedRecords'] = (mydf['col1'] == mydf['col2'])**

so when it will match you will get True And when it won't match you will get False

but the values are non-numeric go for .equals method

syntax:
**mydf['processedRecords'] = mydf['col1'].equals(mydf['col2'])**