# Rowwise calculation using SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

Here is my toy dataframe.

```
library(tibble); library(SparkR)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~var1, ~var2, ~maxofvar1var2,
  1L,    1L,    1L,
  2L,    1L,    2L,
  2L,    3L,    3L,
  NA,    2L,    2L,
  1L,    4L,    4L,
  8L,    5L,    8L)

df <- df %>% as.DataFrame()
```

How can I calculate the rowwise calculation using SparkR to get the max value of var1 and var2 as shown in the 3rd variable in the df above? If there is no rowwise function in SparkR, how can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[To get a maximum  value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37673414/10465355) from a set of columns use [`SparkR::greatest`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/column_nonaggregate_functions):

```
df %>% withColumn("maxOfVars", greatest(df$var1, df$var2))
```

and in general case  higher order functions, like `aggregate` (Spark 2.4 or later), on assembled data .

```
df %>% withColumn("theLastVar", expr("aggregate(array(var1, var2), (x, y) -> y)"))
```

or (version independent) composition of expressions:

```
scols <- c("var1", "var2") %>% purrr::map(column)

sumOfVars <- scols %>%
  purrr::map(function(x) coalesce(x, lit(0)))  %>%
  purrr::reduce(function(x, y) x + y, .init=lit(0))

countOfVars <- scols %>% 
  purrr::map(function(x) ifelse(isNotNull(x), lit(1), lit(0))) %>%
  purrr::reduce(
    function(x, y) x + y, .init=lit(0))

df %>% withColumn("meanOfVars", sumOfVars / countOfVars)
```

Comment: Greatest is an interesting name for a function! Thanks!