# Comparing two dataframe columns to see if they have the same values

Tags: python

I have two dataframe columns that looks something like this:

```
   col1    col2 
0   A2      B8
1   B8      C3
2   D2      A2
```

I want to identify all values in col1 which are not in col2 and visa versa. In the above example, the output would be:

```
C3, D2
```

Both lists are not unique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two columns using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474921/compare-two-columns-using-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

Why not convert each column to a `set` and calculate the symmetric difference?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A2', 'B8', 'D2'],
                   'col2': ['B8', 'C3', 'A2']})

print set(df['col1']).symmetric_difference(set(df['col2']))
```

This prints:

```
set(['C3', 'D2'])
```

EDIT:

If you want to track which elements came from where, you could adapt this and create a new dictionary, like so:

```
col1 = set(df['col1'])
col2 = set(df['col2'])

exclusive_items = {'col1': [x for x in col1 if x not in col2],
                   'col2': [x for x in col2 if x not in col1]}

print exclusive_items
```

Where each key in `exclusive_items` contains as its values the entries unique to that column. This prints:

```
{'col2': ['C3'], 'col1': ['D2']}
```

In fact, as we have sets we could simplify this to:

```
exclusive_items = {'col1': col1-col2,
                   'col2': col2-col1}
```

Comment: With this method, is there a way of knowing which was in col1 and not in col2 and which was in col2 and not in col1?

Comment: @CahnEx not strictly speaking, but I've added a modified version to demonstrate how this could be possible

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A2', 'B8', 'D2'],
                   'col2': ['B8', 'C3', 'A2']})


in_col1_not_in_col2 = list(set(df['col1'])-(set(df['col2'])))
in_col2_not_in_col1 = list(set(df['col2'])-(set(df['col1'])))

print('in_col1_not_in_col2: ')
print(in_col1_not_in_col2)
print('in_col2_not_in_col1: ')
print(in_col2_not_in_col1)
```

> in_col1_not_in_col2: 
>   ['D2']
>
> in_col2_not_in_col1: 
>   ['C3']