# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() when comparing dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

```
df['svc_port'] = np.where(
     min(df['sPort'],df['dPort']) <= 1024, 
     min(df['sPort'],df['dPort']), 
     df['dPort']
)
```

In the above code, `min(df['sPort'],df['dPort']) <= 1024` - the same thing is given in [Compare two columns using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474921/compare-two-columns-using-pandas?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). I am not using any logical operators. just checking a condition and replacing it's values.

Why am I still getting this error?

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: "I am not using any logical operators" - but you are, inside `min`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for an element-wise `min`. The builtin `min` function only works for a single iterable, not multiple of them at a time.

What you're looking for is something along these lines, using `np.minimum`.

```
v = np.minimum(df['sPort'], df['dPort'])
df['svc_port'] = np.where(v <= 1024, v, df['dPort'])
```