# Compare two columns using pandas 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I'm comparing two columns in a dataframe (A & B). I have a method that works (C5). It came from this question:
[Compare two columns using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474921/compare-two-columns-using-pandas/27475029#27475029)

I wondered why I couldn't get the other methods (C1 - C4) to give the correct answer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
                   'B': [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]})

#df['C1'] = 1 [df['A'] == df['B']]

df['C2'] = df['A'].equals(df['B'])

df['C3'] = np.where((df['A'] == df['B']),0,1)

def fun(row):
    if ['A'] == ['B']:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
df['C4'] = df.apply(fun, axis=1)

df['C5'] = df.apply(lambda x : 1 if x['A'] == x['B'] else 0, axis=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
                   'B': [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]})
```

So for `C1` and `C2` need compare columns by `==` or  [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) for boolean mask and then convert it to integers - `True, False` to `1,0`:

```
df['C1'] = (df['A'] == df['B']).astype(int)
df['C2'] = df['A'].eq(df['B']).astype(int)
```

Here is necessary change order `1,0` - for match condition need `1`:

```
df['C3'] = np.where((df['A'] == df['B']),1,0)
```

In function is not selected values of Series, missing `row`:

```
def fun(row):
    if row['A'] == row['B']:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
df['C4'] = df.apply(fun, axis=1)
```

Solution is correct:

```
df['C5'] = df.apply(lambda x : 1 if x['A'] == x['B'] else 0, axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
0  1  1   1   1   1   1   1
1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1
2  1  1   1   1   1   1   1
3  1  1   1   1   1   1   1
4  1  1   1   1   1   1   1
5  2  1   0   0   0   0   0
6  2  0   0   0   0   0   0
7  2  0   0   0   0   0   0
8  2  0   0   0   0   0   0
9  2  0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you need this:

```
def fun(row):
if row['A'] == row['B']:
    return 1
else:
    return 0
```