# Pandas dataframe: changing values in a column based on conditions in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large panel data in a pandas dataframe. The example data can be found [here](https://github.com/ENLK/Py-Projects-/blob/master/example_data.csv):

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('example_data.csv')

df.head()

ID  Year    y   DOB Year_of_death   event
223725  1991    6   1975.0  2021    No
223725  1992    6   1975.0  2021    No
223725  1993    6   1975.0  2021    No
223725  1994    6   1975.0  2021    No
223725  1995    6   1975.0  2021    No
```

I want to change the values in the column `event` so that if the
`Year` value corresponds to the `Year_of_death` value then the observation in `event` for that specific row or `ID` changes to `Yes`, otherwise it remains as `No`.

For example, `ID` 68084329 died in 2012 but has the value `Yes` in every observation in the column `event`. I want to change it so that only the row with `Year` 2012 for this `ID` has `Yes` in `event`. The other `event` values should remain as `No`.

```
df.loc[df['ID'] == '68084329']

ID         Year    y    DOB  Year_of_death  event
68084329    1991    6   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    1992    5   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    1993    5   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    1994    6   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    1995    6   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    1996    5   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    1997    6   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    1998    5   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    1999    6   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    2000    6   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    2001    6   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    2002    5   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    2003    6   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    2004    5   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    2005    5   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    2006    6   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    2007    6   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    2008    6   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    2010    5   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    2011    5   1942.0  2012    Yes
68084329    2012    0   1942.0  2012    Yes
```

How do I make these changes for a large DataFrame with many IDs in accordance with the above conditions?

Comment: Not sure where the ID matters here, so I think `df['event'] = np.where(df['Year'].eq(df['Year_of_death']), 'Yes','No')` would do it

Comment: Works very nicely here, thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two columns using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474921/compare-two-columns-using-pandas)

Comment: @Ben.T I feel that is the single best feature in SO, have others help you with the right search terms

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[df[Year'] == df['Year of Death'], 'Event'] = 'Yes'
```

That worked in a similar piece of code I was writing.