# How to validate a column based on another column in pandas dataframe (maybe use pandas-schema), Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` with 2 columns `price` and `max_price`. I want have these validations:

1. the values in `max_price` column must be `=> 0`.
2. the values in `price` column must be `=> 0`, but also be `<= max_price` in the corresponding row.

I have the following code. I only know how to check `=> 0` for the `price` column, but don't know how to check if it is higher than the value in `max_price` column.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_schema import Column, Schema
from pandas_schema.validation import InRangeValidation


df = pd.DataFrame({'price': [1, 10, 20], 'max_price': [10, 5, 25]})

schema = Schema([
    Column('price', [InRangeValidation(min=0)]),  # how to check with the column `max_price`?
    Column('max_price', [InRangeValidation(min=0)])
])

errors = schema.validate(df)

for error in errors:
    print(error)
```

Here, the 2nd row in `df` is invalid, since the `price` is 10 while the `max_price` is just 5.

Could you please show me how to make the code correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Lst=df['price'].values
row=0
for v in df['max_price'].values:
    if(Lst[row]>v):
       print("error at row:",row)
    row=row+1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution checks the value in a standalone manner. But do you know how to use pandas_schema to solve it? Because it is more inline with the rest of my code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474921/compare-two-columns-using-pandas