# Pandas DataFrame add column with text from two other columns depending on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I add a column with header `MergeName` to a Pandas `DataFrame` that has the text from column `ShortName`, but if `ShortName` is "None", then the `MergeName` value should equal the `Plaintiffs` column value?

This is the Pandas `DataFrame` data:

```
      Plaintiffs Gender ShortName
0           None   None      None
1           None   None      None
2    Donald Duck      M      None
3   Minnie Mouse      F    Minnie
4           None   None      None
5       John Doe      M       Doe
6           None   None      None
7           None   None      None
8           None   None      None
9           None   None      None
10          None   None      None
```

Thanks!

I've tried so many different things and nothing seems to work. Usually the result is only all the data from the else condition is added to the `MergeName` column including "None" values. Code I've tried include:

```
PlaintiffsTbl['MergeName'] = np.where(PlaintiffsTbl['ShortName'] is None, PlaintiffsTbl['Plaintiffs'],  PlaintiffsTbl['ShortName'])
```

```
PlaintiffsTbl['MergeName'] = PlaintiffsTbl['ShortName']
PlaintiffsTbl.loc[PlaintiffsTbl['MergeName'] == None, 'MergeName'] = PlaintiffsTbl['Plaintiffs']
```

```
PlaintiffsTbl['MergeName'] = [PlaintiffsTbl['Plaintiffs'] if PlaintiffsTbl['ShortName'] is None else PlaintiffsTbl['ShortName']]
```

**Thank you Amir Hossein Shahdaei!**
**This code does what I was looking for:**

```
PlaintiffsTbl['MergeName'] = PlaintiffsTbl['ShortName']
PlaintiffsTbl['MergeName'] = PlaintiffsTbl['MergeName'].fillna(PlaintiffsTbl['Plaintiffs'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .fillna function and after making MergeName from ShortName col fill null values of it with MergeName col

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = [
        ['a', None],
        ['b', 1],
        [None, 2],
        [None, None],], 
    columns = ['Plaintiffs', 'ShortName']
)
df['MergeName'] = df['ShortName']
df['MergeName'] = df['MergeName'].fillna(df['Plaintiffs'])
df

    Plaintiffs  ShortName   MergeName
0   a           NaN         a
1   b           1.0         1.0
2   None        2.0         2.0
3   None        NaN         None
```

Comment: You solved in 5 minutes something that I've been struggling with for two days. So frustrating. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
data = [[None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None],
        ['Donald Duck', 'M', None, 'Donald Duck'], ['Minnie Mouse', 'F', 'Minnie', 'Minnie'],
        [None, None, None, None], ['John Doe', 'M', 'Doe', 'Doe']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Plaintiffs', 'Gender', 'ShortName', 'MergeName'])
```

`df`

```
Plaintiffs      Gender  ShortName
0   None        None    None    
1   None        None    None    
2   Donald Duck M       None    
3   Minnie MouseF       Minnie  
4   None        None    None    
5   John Doe    M       Doe
```

**Code**

```
df['MergeName'] = df['ShortName'].fillna(df['Plaintiffs'])
```

`df`

```
    Plaintiffs  Gender  ShortName   MergeName
0   None        None    None    None
1   None        None    None    None
2   Donald Duck M       None    Donald Duck
3   Minnie MouseF       Minnie  Minnie
4   None        None    None    None
5   John Doe    M       Doe     Doe
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `np.where` like this, not like your first trying:

```
PlaintiffsTbl['MergeName'] = np.where(PlaintiffsTbl['ShortName'], PlaintiffsTbl['ShortName'], PlaintiffsTbl['Plaintiffs'])
```

For example, the full code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

PlaintiffsTbl = pd.DataFrame({
    'Plaintiffs': [None, None, 'Donald Duck', 'Minnie Mouse', None, 'John Doe', None, None, None, None, None],
    'Gender': [None, None, 'M', 'F', None, 'M', None, None, None, None, None],
    'ShortName': [None, None, None, 'Minnie', None, 'Doe', None, None, None, None, None],
})

print(PlaintiffsTbl)
"""
      Plaintiffs Gender ShortName
0           None   None      None
1           None   None      None
2    Donald Duck      M      None
3   Minnie Mouse      F    Minnie
4           None   None      None
5       John Doe      M       Doe
6           None   None      None
7           None   None      None
8           None   None      None
9           None   None      None
10          None   None      None
"""

PlaintiffsTbl['MergeName'] = np.where(PlaintiffsTbl['ShortName'], PlaintiffsTbl['ShortName'], PlaintiffsTbl['Plaintiffs'])

print(PlaintiffsTbl)
"""
      Plaintiffs Gender ShortName    MergeName
0           None   None      None         None
1           None   None      None         None
2    Donald Duck      M      None  Donald Duck
3   Minnie Mouse      F    Minnie       Minnie
4           None   None      None         None
5       John Doe      M       Doe          Doe
6           None   None      None         None
7           None   None      None         None
8           None   None      None         None
9           None   None      None         None
10          None   None      None         None
"""
```

For more information about `np.where`, see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: Thank you! Is this faster than .fillna?

Answer (score 1):

[the inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474921/compare-two-columns-using-pandas)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
di = {
    'Plaintiffs': ['Donald Duck', 'Minnie Mouse', None],
    'ShortName': [None, 'Minnie', None]
    }
d = pd.DataFrame(di)
d
```

yields

```
     Plaintiffs ShortName
0   Donald Duck      None
1  Minnie Mouse    Minnie
2          None      None
```

if it's just a simply one branching

```py
cond = (d['ShortName'].isna()) & (d['Plaintiffs'].notna())
d['MergeName'] = np.where(cond, d['Plaintiffs'], d['ShortName'])
d
```

or this (suitable with more conditions and choices)

```py
conditions = [
    (d['ShortName'].isna()) & (d['Plaintiffs'].notna())
]
choices = [d['Plaintiffs']]
d['MergeName'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=d['ShortName'])
d
```

yields the same

```
     Plaintiffs ShortName    MergeName
0   Donald Duck      None  Donald Duck
1  Minnie Mouse    Minnie       Minnie
2          None      None         None
```

if it has more than one choice, just add into the list

```py
conditions = [
    (d['ShortName'].isna()) & (d['Plaintiffs'].notna()),
    d['ShortName'].notna()
]
choices = [d['Plaintiffs'], d['ShortName']]
d['MergeName'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
d
```

yields

```
     Plaintiffs ShortName    MergeName
0   Donald Duck      None  Donald Duck
1  Minnie Mouse    Minnie       Minnie
2          None      None            0
```